# Есть числа, например [59, 61, 62]. Как получить 60, а если [59, 60, 61, 62], то 63?

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть, например, числа 59 60 61 62. Я удаляю 60. Получается уже будет 59 61 62. Как я могу найти число 60 при загрузке страницы? Или если числа идут подряд найти в данном случае 63? Как найти последнее я знаю,  а вот без кастылей первое - нет. Пробовал циклом и математикой, но получается криво и с ошибками.

Comment: зачем его сначала удалять, а потом искать?

Comment: Вы уточните задачу. Числа всегда отличаются на 1? Если на входе `[59, 60, 61]`, то надо найти `58` или `62`? И почему? Если на вход пришло `[1, 2, 99]`, то какой должен быть результат?

Comment: Не пойму, как может "циклом и математикой" получаться криво и с ошибками. Нашли минимальное и максимальное число в массиве, циклом перебираете в этом диапазоне и проверяете - есть такое число в массиве или нет. Единственное, что можно сделать для полноты картины - это увеличить цикл на одну итерацию, чтобы при отсутствии "прорех" в массиве, получить следующее после максимального числа

Comment: @slippyk у каждой анкеты есть свой ID. Я привёл для примера 4 числа. Например, нажал удалить анкету с номером 60. В следующий раз, когда необходимо добавить анкету, я хочу использовать не следующее число, а если было удалено число взять его, а если его нет, то использовать последнее плюс 1

Comment: @yaant ответил выше

Comment: @deonis ответил выше

Comment: Но зачем? Если (к примеру) кто-то где-то сохранил ссылку на анкету, потом она была удалена, и он перейдет по ссылке, то ему вместо надписи "анкета удалена" будет показана другая, совершенно левая анкета? Вы уверены, что это нормально?

Comment: @yaant анкета это имя айди и процент/рубли которые достаются из базы только для куратора проекта. Добавить анкету означает добавить выше данные и передать ей тому для кого была создана она. Он в свою очередь просто отправляет заявки в таблицу. Ничего секретного и прочего :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно как-то так сделать:

```js
function findHole(arr){
  return 1 + (arr.sort().find((el, i, arr) => 1 + el !== arr[i + 1]) || 0)
}

console.log(findHole([1,2,4,5])) //3
console.log(findHole([])) //1
console.log(findHole([1,2,3,4,5])) //6
```